# Having trouble with remove method of Custom Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm writing my own Linked list and I'm running into an error with my remove(E obj) method repeatedly. Though it removes the object I want it to, it also removes the very last object in the list. When i want it to remove the very last object, it removes it, but also the second to last one. I am not quite sure what is going wrong. My Linked list uses an int variable to keep track of the size and two helper methods, indexOf(E obj) and getNode(int index). Here are my remove methods:

```
public E remove(int index)
{
    if(index > 0 && index < size)
    {
        Node<E> temp = getNode(index);
        getNode(index - 1).setNext(getNode(index + 1));
        size--;
        return temp.getValue();
    }
    else if(index == 0)
    {
        Node<E> temp = getNode(0);          
        head.setNext(getNode(1));
        size--;
        return temp.getValue();
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean remove(E obj)
{
    if(!contains(obj))
        return false;
    int index = indexOf(obj);
    remove(index);
    size--;
    return true;
}
```

These are the indexOf and getNode methods I am using as helper methods.

```
private int indexOf(E obj)
{
    int index = 0;
    Node<E> n = head.getNext();
    while(n != null)
    {
        if(!n.getValue().equals(obj))
            index++;
        else
            return index;
        n = n.getNext();
    }
    return -1;
}

private Node<E> getNode(int index)
{
    Node<E> n = head.getNext();
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        n = n.getNext();
    }
    return n;
}
```

I have a tester file, and this is the code which is currently in the file:

```
a.add(1);
a.add(2);
a.add(3);       
a.add(4);
a.add(5);
a.remove(new Integer(3));
print(a);
```

The print method works correctly, but here it is just in case you want to see.

```
public static void print(MyLinkedList list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        int s = (int)(list.get(i));
        System.out.printf("%d, ", s);
    }
}
```

So the above code prints the following: 1, 2, 4,

And when I remove the integer 5 instead of 3, it prints: 1, 2, 3,

What am I doing wrong? I am unable to debug my code. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're decrementing size twice. You decrement size in the function call that takes an object of type E as well as in the function that takes the index. Because of this, when you print, the last node is skipped.

Comment: I"ve been looking at every complicated solution, and the answer was the simplest one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)